# Symfony 2.3 how to hide/show image via checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, checkbox

My problem is that I want to be able to hide or show an uploaded image via checkbox, i.e. I uploaded image A, a checkbox will come along with it that if checked hide image, when unchecked show image. I was thinking of giving them values like 1 and 0 but I have no idea where should I do this, is it in Javascript? or in symfony forms/entities/controller?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for you will be to use Javascript. I would suggest you the following steps:

1/ Integrate a checkbox in Symfony form .

2/ Hide the checkbox with javascript.

3/ When the image is uploaded, display the image (see an extract of code below for that step) + display the checkbox

4/ Detect the event (click on the checkbox), get the value of it and according to its value, hide or display the image

An extract of code that might help you for displaying the image:

```
$(function() {
$(".upload-file input").each(function(){
    $(this).on("change", function(){
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");

                // Show picture fields
                if (typeof hideShowFieldsPictureForm !== 'undefined') {
                    hideShowFieldsPictureForm();
                }
                if ($('#hideShowPixFields').length) {
                    $('#hideShowPixFields').removeClass('hidden');
                }

            };
        }
    });
});

if ($('#uploadFileBtn').length) {
    $('#uploadFileBtn').click(function() {
        $('.upload-file input[type=file]').click();
    });
}
```

});

And in the twig:

```
   {# Main Picture #}
    <table class="upload-file">
        <tr>{{ form_errors(form.picture.file) }}</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(form.picture.file) }}
                <div id="imagePreview"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! but could you explain to me the .removeClass? and the reader.onloadend? I want to know what they are for.

Comment: .onloadend, is lauched at the end of the upload. .removeClass is to unhide some section